# Get the Control on a page by passing URL? Also get the current page URL?

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

My Requirement: I want to know which page I am currently in so that if any test fails I want to pass the current page's URL to a method and get the home button link. Ultimately navigating to the home link in case of any exception.

Is there a way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

The URL should be in the address bar of the browser, just read it out of there.

One way of reading out the value is to record an assertion on the value in the address bar, then copy the part of the code in the recorded assertion method that accesses the value.

Another way is to use the cross-hairs tool to select the address area, then (click the double-chevron icon to open the left hand pane and) add the UI control for the selected area. Then access the value.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the top Browser:

```
BrowserWindow bw = null;

        try
        {
            Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads;
            var browser = new BrowserWindow() /*{ TechnologyName = "MSAA" }*/;

            PropertyExpressionCollection f = new PropertyExpressionCollection();
            f.Add("TechnologyName", "MSAA");
            f.Add("ClassName", "IEFrame");
            f.Add("ControlType", "Window");
            browser.SearchProperties.AddRange(f);

            UITestControlCollection coll = browser.FindMatchingControls();

            // get top of browser stack
            foreach (BrowserWindow win in coll)
            {
                bw = win;
                break;
            }

            String url = bw.Uri.ToString(); //this is the value you want to save


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception getting active (top) browser:   - ------" + e.Message);

        }
        finally
        {
            Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.UIThreadOnly;
        }
```